# GROUPBY Parameter - SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report

how can I group my parameter values?
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the query used for the `ReportParameter1` ?

Comment: Sounds like you need `Distinct` in the query driving that parameter.

Comment: ReportParameter1 is value from DataSet1, field: Sho_Region

Comment: Rather than populating parameters from your main dataset (which may well contain non-distinct values), have you considered creating a dataset which would return just the values that would populate the parameter list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters are probably being pulled from a dataset. You may need to create a new dataset and modify your query to just have the parameters you want to display.

You will want to add DISTINCT to your query, like this:

> select DISTINCT SHO_REGION from TABLENAME

Then just populate your parameters with your new dataset. Bam, done.